# Extract directory from path

Tags: string, bash, path

In my script I need the **directory** of the file I am working with.  For example, the *file*=**"stuff/backup/file.zip"**. I need a way to get the string "**stuff/backup/**" from the variable `$file`.

Comment: duplicates: [get parent directory of a file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700119/995714), [Get the parent directory of a given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351916/44425), [Getting the parent of a directory in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426058/995714)

Comment: @phuclv This question was asked on 2011-06-28, before all of those questions linked were posted (2016-11-20, 2017-03-16, and 2011-12-08, respectively).

Comment: @Edwin time is irrelevant on SO. [The question with a better set of answers remain open](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/995714)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```bash
dirname -- "$file";
```

is what you are looking for

Comment: +1, beat me to it. would have been quicker but was prompoted to enter more than `dirname $file`

Comment: `dirname "$file"`, rather. Without the quotes this will misbehave if the file or directory name has spaces.

Comment: fml, the question should be extract absolute dir from file, how do I do that? dirname yields relative path I guess

Comment: It is outstanding how difficult this is to accomplish in a win Batch script -- another reason not to use them I suppose!

Answer (score 60):

```
dirname $file
```

will output

```
stuff/backup
```

which is the opposite of `basename`:

```
basename $file
```

would output

```
file.zip
```

Comment: I figured Matt would be able to figure it from there (man dirname) :)

Comment: I think we are all Matt's here. Just a guess. But I was just trying to distinguish my answer from yours. =)

Comment: Yeah, I do use basename a lot too, it's very nifty =) But I could just not find anything about returning the file's dir on google! I guess I wasn't looking up the right words.
Hah, all 3 of us Matt's? :D

Comment: Consider adding the necessary quotes to ensure that these commands work with names containing spaces (glob characters, etc).

Answer (score 8):

Using `${file%/*}` like suggested by Urvin/LuFFy is technically better since you won't rely on an external command. To get the basename in the same way you could do `${file##*/}`. It's unnecessary to use an external command unless you need to.

```
file="/stuff/backup/file.zip"
filename=${1##*/}     # file.zip
directory=${1%/*}     # /stuff/backup
```

It would also be fully POSIX compliant this way. Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: There is *one* case where `dirname` has an advantage over the (more efficient) built-in approach, and that's if you aren't certain that your path is fully-qualified to start with. If you have `file=file.zip`, `dirname "$file"` will return `.`, whereas `${file%/*}` will return `file.zip`.

Comment: ...of course, you can branch: `case $file in */*) dir=${file%/*};; *) dir=.;; esac` is still POSIX-y and addresses the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For getting `directorypath` from the `filepath`:

```
file="stuff/backup/file.zip"
dirPath=${file%/*}/
echo ${dirPath}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$ dirname /home/~username/stuff/backup/file.zip`

It will return `/home/~username/stuff/backup/`