# Getting the parent of a directory in Bash

Tags: bash, directory, dirname

If I have a file path such as...

```
/home/smith/Desktop/Test
/home/smith/Desktop/Test/
```

How do I change the string so it will be the parent directory?

e.g.

```
/home/smith/Desktop
/home/smith/Desktop/
```

Comment: You can simply use '`..`', but maybe that isn't quite what you had in mind.

Comment: '..' can only be used for directory path and not for path to a file.

Comment: Unrelated but what I was actually looking for was abbreviated paths: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381113/how-do-i-shorten-the-current-directory-path-shown-on-terminal

Answer (score 535, accepted):

```
dir=/home/smith/Desktop/Test
parentdir="$(dirname "$dir")"
```

Works if there is a trailing slash, too.

Comment: the quotes inside are important or you're gonna loose all your data

Comment: and the variant I'm using to get the parent of current working directory:  
    `parentdir=$(dirname \`pwd\`)`

Comment: The parent of current working directory is simply `..`.

Comment: If you want 2nd/3rd/4th parent directories, then see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426058/bash-get-the-parent-directory-of-current-directory/40632749#40632749

Comment: Note, this method is insecure for "ugly" names. A name like "-rm -rf" will break the desired behavior. Probably "." will, too. I don't know if that's the best way, but I've created a separate "correctness-focused" question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700119/get-parent-directory-for-a-file-in-bash

Comment: @asdfasdfads Can you explain your comment? Why would data be lost if the quotes are omitted?

Comment: @Christopher Shroba Yeah, I omitted the quotes and then my HDD ended up partially wiped. I don't remember exactly what has happened: presumably an unquoted whitespaced directory made it erase the parent dir instead of the target one - my script just erased the /home/xxx/ folder.

Comment: oh okay, so there's nothing about the command that would cause any data to get lost unless you're already issuing a delete command, right?  It was just a matter of the path you were trying to remove getting split on a space character and removing much more than expected?

Comment: @TheGrimmScientist don't run your variant from "`/tmp/robert && sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`".

Comment: basename $(dirname $(pwd))

Answer (score 45):

Clearly the parent directory is given by simply appending the dot-dot filename:

```
/home/smith/Desktop/Test/..     # unresolved path
```

But you must want the *resolved* path (an absolute path without any dot-dot path components):

```
/home/smith/Desktop             # resolved path
```

The problem with the top answers that use `dirname`, is that they don't work when you enter a path with dot-dots:

```
$ dir=~/Library/../Desktop/../..
$ parentdir="$(dirname "$dir")"
$ echo $parentdir
/Users/username/Library/../Desktop/..   # not fully resolved
```

**This is more powerful**:

```
dir=/home/smith/Desktop/Test
parentdir=$(builtin cd $dir; pwd)
```

You can feed it `/home/smith/Desktop/Test/..`, but also more complex paths like:

```
$ dir=~/Library/../Desktop/../..
$ parentdir=$(builtin cd $dir; pwd)
$ echo $parentdir
/Users                                  # the fully resolved path!
```

NOTE: use of `builtin` ensures no user defined function variant of `cd` is called, but rather the default utility form which has no output.

Comment: Using `eval` is NOT great if there is any chance of parsing user input that could put you somewhere you don't expect or run bad things against your system. Can you use `pushd $dir 2>&1 >/dev/null && pwd && popd 2>&1 >/dev/null` instead of the `eval`?

Comment: You don't need `eval` at all: just do `parentdir=$(cd -- "$dir" && pwd)`. Since the `cd` is run in a subshell, you don't need to `cd` back to where we were. The `--` is here in case the expansion of `$dir` starts with a hyphen. The `&&` is just to prevent `parentdir` to have a non-empty content when the `cd` didn't suceed.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks. updated the answer based on your advice

Comment: I used this to get the parent directory of an application: `dir=$(builtin cd "../../.."; pwd)` when everything else failed, due to a space in the path name. The application was a pseudo-app built by Platypus, where the actual script was buried inside. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

Just use `echo $(cd ../ && pwd)` while working in the directory whose parent dir you want to find out. This chain also has the added benefit of not having trailing slashes.

Comment: You don't need `echo` here.

Comment: Yes he does. Otherwise there will be a side effect that the current directory is changed.

Comment: Unnecessary subshell, you may as well do `echo ${PWD%/*}`

Answer (score 21):

...but what is "seen [here](http://arkbashtipsandtricks.blogspot.ch/2006/02/how-to-get-parent-directory-of-folder.html)" is broken. Here's the fix:

```sh
> pwd
/home/me
> x='Om Namah Shivaya'
> mkdir "$x" && cd "$x"
/home/me/Om Namah Shivaya
> parentdir="$(dirname "$(pwd)")"
> echo $parentdir
/home/me
```

Answer (score 18):

## Motivation for another answer

I like very short, clear, guaranteed code.  Bonus point if it does not run an external program, since the day you need to process a huge number of entries, it will be noticeably faster.

## Principle

Not sure about what guarantees you have and want, so offering anyway.

If you have guarantees you can do it with very short code. The idea is to use bash text substitution feature to cut the last slash and whatever follows.

Answer from simple to more complex cases of the original question.

### If path is guaranteed to end without any slash (in and out)

```
P=/home/smith/Desktop/Test ; echo "${P%/*}"
/home/smith/Desktop
```

### If path is guaranteed to end with exactly one slash (in and out)

```
P=/home/smith/Desktop/Test/ ; echo "${P%/*/}/"
/home/smith/Desktop/
```

### If input path may end with zero or one slash (not more) and you want output path to end without slash

```
for P in \
    /home/smith/Desktop/Test \
    /home/smith/Desktop/Test/
do
    P_ENDNOSLASH="${P%/}" ; echo "${P_ENDNOSLASH%/*}"
done

/home/smith/Desktop
/home/smith/Desktop
```

### If input path may have many extraneous slashes and you want output path to end without slash

```
for P in \
    /home/smith/Desktop/Test \
    /home/smith/Desktop/Test/ \
    /home/smith///Desktop////Test// 
do
    P_NODUPSLASH="${P//\/*(\/)/\/}"
    P_ENDNOSLASH="${P_NODUPSLASH%%/}"
    echo "${P_ENDNOSLASH%/*}";   
done

/home/smith/Desktop
/home/smith/Desktop
/home/smith/Desktop
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Since it seems like he was looking for a way to do this from within a script (find the script's current directory and it's parent and do something relative to where the script lives) this is a great answer and you can have even more control over whether the input has a trailing slash or not by using parameter expansion against `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` which would be the full path to the script if it wasn't  sourced via `source` or `.`.

Answer (score 12):

If you need just the name of parent directory:

```
parent_dir_name=$(basename $(dirname $PWD))
```

Answer (score 9):

If `/home/smith/Desktop/Test/../` is what you want:

```
dirname 'path/to/child/dir'
```

as seen [here](http://arkbashtipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2006/02/how-to-get-parent-directory-of-folder.html).

Comment: sorry, I mean in like a bash script, I have a variable with the file path

Comment: Running that code gives me the error `bash: dirname 'Test': syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "'Test'")`. Linked code is also wrong.

Comment: try just running `dirname Test` from the directory `Test` is in.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you need absolute paths you may want to take an extra step:

```
child='/home/smith/Desktop/Test/'
parent=$(dirname "$child")
abs_parent=$(realpath "$parent")
```

Comment: realpath is not posix

Comment: Good to know. It's a software part of gnu core utils which may or may not be installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

use this : `export MYVAR="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname $PWD)")")")"` if you want 4th parent directory

`export MYVAR="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname $PWD)")")"` 
if you want 3rd parent directory

`export MYVAR="$(dirname "$(dirname $PWD)")"` 
if you want 2nd parent directory

Answer (score 0):

ugly but efficient

```
function Parentdir()
```

{

```
local lookFor_ parent_ switch_ i_

lookFor_="$1"

#if it is not a file, we need the grand parent
[ -f "$lookFor_" ] || switch_="/.."

#length of search string
i_="${#lookFor_}"

#remove string one by one until it make sens for the system
while [ "$i_" -ge 0 ] && [ ! -d "${lookFor_:0:$i_}" ];
do
    let i_--
done

#get real path
parent_="$(realpath "${lookFor_:0:$i_}$switch_")" 

#done
echo "
lookFor_: $1
{lookFor_:0:$i_}: ${lookFor_:0:$i_}
realpath {lookFor_:0:$i_}: $(realpath ${lookFor_:0:$i_})
parent_: $parent_ 
"
```

}

```
    lookFor_: /home/Om Namah Shivaya
{lookFor_:0:6}: /home/
realpath {lookFor_:0:6}: /home
parent_: /home 


lookFor_: /var/log
{lookFor_:0:8}: /var/log
realpath {lookFor_:0:8}: /UNIONFS/var/log
parent_: /UNIONFS/var 


lookFor_: /var/log/
{lookFor_:0:9}: /var/log/
realpath {lookFor_:0:9}: /UNIONFS/var/log
parent_: /UNIONFS/var 


lookFor_: /tmp//res.log/..
{lookFor_:0:6}: /tmp//
realpath {lookFor_:0:6}: /tmp
parent_: / 


lookFor_: /media/sdc8/../sdc8/Debian_Master//a
{lookFor_:0:35}: /media/sdc8/../sdc8/Debian_Master//
realpath {lookFor_:0:35}: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master
parent_: /media/sdc8 


lookFor_: /media/sdc8//Debian_Master/../Debian_Master/a
{lookFor_:0:44}: /media/sdc8//Debian_Master/../Debian_Master/
realpath {lookFor_:0:44}: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master
parent_: /media/sdc8 


lookFor_: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master/../Debian_Master/For_Debian
{lookFor_:0:53}: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master/../Debian_Master/For_Debian
realpath {lookFor_:0:53}: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master/For_Debian
parent_: /media/sdc8/Debian_Master 


lookFor_: /tmp/../res.log
{lookFor_:0:8}: /tmp/../
realpath {lookFor_:0:8}: /
parent_: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Started from the idea/comment Charles Duffy - Dec 17 '14 at 5:32 on the topic [Get current directory name (without full path) in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script)

```
#!/bin/bash
#INFO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script
# comment : by Charles Duffy - Dec 17 '14 at 5:32
# at the beginning :



declare -a dirName[]

function getDirNames(){
dirNr="$(  IFS=/ read -r -a dirs <<<"${dirTree}"; printf '%s\n' "$((${#dirs[@]} - 1))"  )"

for(( cnt=0 ; cnt < ${dirNr} ; cnt++))
  do
      dirName[$cnt]="$( IFS=/ read -r -a dirs <<<"$PWD"; printf '%s\n' "${dirs[${#dirs[@]} - $(( $cnt+1))]}"  )"
      #information – feedback
      echo "$cnt :  ${dirName[$cnt]}"
  done
}

dirTree=$PWD;
getDirNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

if for whatever reason you are interested in navigating up a specific number of directories you could also do: `nth_path=$(cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && cd ../../../ && pwd)`. This would give 3 parents directories up

Comment: why ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} instead of simpler $BASH_SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, going from `/some/folder/foo/bar/..` to `/some/folder/foo` is rather trivial using `buildin cd <...>; pwd`.

This however will have side effects when working with relative path as cd + pwd will resolve to an absolute path.

If you want to resolve `folder/foo/bar/..` into `folder/foo`, you can use `sed`:

```
relative_path=folder/foo/bar/..
echo $relative_path | sed -E 's/(.*)\/(.*)\/\.\./\1/g'
```

The regexp used above is basically replacing any `pat1/pat2/..` by `pat1`.

That can also be used as a function:

```
function relative_parent() {
  echo "$1" | sed -E 's/(.*)\/(.*)\/\.\./\1/g'
}
```

and called as:

```
relative_parent $relative_path
```

Answer (score -4):

This would go up to the parent folder

```
cd ../
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question the OP was asking. This command will change the current directory during a terminal session. The OP was asking how to obtain string that contains the parent directory, without actually moving directories.