# How to get previous directory in bash script?

Tags: node.js, bash, aws-lambda-layers

I'm now writing bash script to get project directory in my project. Following is my folder structure. When I go `api` folder and type `pwd`, I will get `"/Users/ppshein/Documents/projects/api"` but what I want is I want to get `"/Users/ppshein/Documents/projects/my-layers"` from `api` folder.

```
├── README.md
├── api
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── report
├── serverless.yml
├── webpack.config.js
└── my-layers
```

Is there anyway we can do in bash script?

Comment: `$(pwd)/../my-layers` ?

Comment: @armnotstrong it does not work.

Comment: @PPShein what exactly did not work about it? Also, see [How do I navigate up one directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703698/how-do-i-navigate-up-one-directory-from-the-terminal).

Comment: @PPShein : If you don't want to invoke `pwd`, you could also do a `other_dir="$PWD/../my-layers"`. If you don't want to see the `..` inside the path, and have `readlink` installed, do a `other_dir=$(readlink -f ../my-layers)`. If you don't have `readlink`, you maybe have `realpath`. In this case, it would be `other_dir=$(realpath ../my-layers)`.

Comment: duplicates: [get parent directory of a file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700119/995714), [Get the parent directory of a given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351916/44425), [Getting the parent of a directory in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426058/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent directory like so:

```
parent="$(dirname "$(pwd)")"
```

Then

```
"${parent}/my-layers"
```

See [Getting the parent of a directory in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426058/getting-the-parent-of-a-directory-in-bash) for more details about how you can get the parent directory

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this trick

`BASE_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -m $0))`

this will get the dir that contains your script with variable `${BASE_DIR}`. normally, it's the root dir of your project, or at least you could find something to work with. `../` something like that.

The good news is that it doesn't use a command like `pwd` which maybe environment-related. So that you could execute your script anywhere you like, especially useful in a crontab.