# How to get the path part of a full file name with macOS bash?

Tags: bash, path

**Edit** I am still wondering why this question is closed. `Parent` is not what I was looking for. Maybe somebody can explain why this question is not opened again? Thank you.

This question has **nothing** to do with "parent"! So, I do not know why the question was closed and an answer for a parent directory was mentioned.

A question about bash on macOS

I have a file name which is something like

```
/Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder/file.txt
```

But I only need the path part

```
/Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder
```

with or without the last `/`, both is OK.

I have no idea how to do it, so I can't provide anything I have tried.

**//Edit:** There is a discussion now if I asked for the parent path or not. I didn't. Here is the definition what a [parent path](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/parent-folder) is.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: In plain bash:  `path='/Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder/file.txt'; echo "${path%/*}"`

Comment: so many duplicates: [get parent directory of a file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700119/995714), [Get the parent directory of a given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351916/44425), [Getting the parent of a directory in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426058/995714), [Extract directory from path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6509650/995714), [How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/995714)

Comment: @phuclv No, because I do not search for the parent directory. I already found the solution: `dirname`

Comment: `/Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder` **is** the parent folder of `/Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder/file.txt`. All the above questions ask exactly that and the answer is also `dirname`. Did you even read them?

Comment: @phuclv This is not the parent path. The parent path would be `/Users/johndoe/Desktop/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dirname /Users/johndoe/Desktop/folder/file.txt
```

Comment: I thought I have to do something with `cut`