# Find directories where a text is found in a specific file

Tags: linux, sh

How can I find the directories where a text is found in a specific file? E.g. I want to get all the directories in "/var/www/" that contain the text "foo-bundle" in the `composer.json` file. I have a command that already does it:

`find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type f -print | grep -i 'composer.json' | xargs grep -i '"foo-bundle"'`

However I want to make an `sh` script that gets all those directories and do things with them. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

## [find](/questions/tagged/find)

Your current command is almost there, instead off using `xargs` with `grep`, lets:

1. Move the `grep` to an [`-exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)
2. Use `xargs` to pass the result to [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) to show only the parent folder

```sh
find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep -l "foo-bundle" {} /dev/null \; | xargs dirname
```

If you only want to search for `composer.json` files, we can include the `-iname` option like so:

```sh
find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*composer.json' -exec grep -l "foo-bundle" {} /dev/null \; | xargs dirname
```

If the `| xargs dirname` doesn't give enough data, we can extend it so we [can loop over the results of `find`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find) using a `while read` like so:

```sh
find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*composer.json' -exec grep -l "foo-bundle" {} /dev/null \; | while read -r line ; do
    parent="$(dirname ${line%%:*})"
    echo "$parent"
done
```

---

## [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

We can use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) [to search for all files containing a specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux).

After [looping over each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-output-line-in-a-loop), we can

1. [Remove behind the `:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168371/how-can-i-remove-all-text-after-a-character-in-bash) to get the filepath
2. Use `dirname` to get the [parent folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509650/extract-directory-from-path)

---

Consider this file setup, were `/test/b/composer.json` contains `foo-bundle`

```
➜  /tmp tree
.
├── test
│   ├── a
│   │   └── composer.json
│   └── b
│       └── composer.json
└── test.sh
```

When running the following `test.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

grep -rw '/tmp/test' --include '*composer.json' -e 'foo-bundle' | while read -r line ; do
    parent="$(dirname ${line%:*})"
    echo "$parent"
done
```

The result is as expected, the path to folder `b`:

```
/tmp/test/b
```

Comment: This is a recursive grep, my directories are too large for that. I only need the grep over the composer.json file

Comment: Oeps, forgot to add that. We can use `--include '*composer.json'` to let grep only search the composer files. I've edited my answer!

Comment: It's still a recursive grep. It takes too long. I should read only the second level directory

Comment: However, I think I can get it combining my find command with your while logic. I'll give a try

Comment: Ahh, not sure if `grep` has an `max-depth` like option. I'd recommend using the first `find` way.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find all files, containing a particular piece of text, you can use:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep -l "composer.json" {} /dev/null \;
```

The result is a list of filenames. Now all you need to do is to get a way to launch the command `dirname` on all of them. (I tried using a simple pipe, but that would have been too easy :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @0stone0 for leading the way. I finally got it with:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

find /var/www -maxdepth 2 -type f -print | grep -i 'composer.json' | xargs grep -i 'foo-bundle' | while read -r line ; do
    parent="$(dirname ${line%%:*})"
    echo "$parent"
done
```

Comment: Please see my [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69766911/5625547). We can remove 1 pipe by using the `-iname` option of `find`. Might increase the speed since we don't need to use a pipe.